# Having trouble with JSON on Woocommerce Rest API's

Tags: json, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am having difficulty getting the product stock/product quantities to update on my woocommerce page from my database. I was able to get other portions (like customer notes) to update successfully, but am unsure what i'm doing wrong.

This is the recent code i've tried

```
* The following code creates the JSON request body.
                * The JSON created by this code is shown below.
                loJsonReq = CreateObject('Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonObject')
                loJsonReq.UpdateNumber("product.id","3341")
                loJsonReq.UpdateBool("product.inventory_quantity",5)

                * The JSON request body created by the above code:

                * {
                *   "product": {
                *     "id": 3341
                *     "inventory_quantity": 5
                *   }
                * }

                loSbReq = CreateObject('Chilkat_9_5_0.StringBuilder')
                loJsonReq.EmitSb(loSbReq)

                loRest.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/json")

                loSbJson = CreateObject('Chilkat_9_5_0.StringBuilder')
                lnSuccess = loRest.FullRequestSb("PUT","/admin/products/#{id}.json",loSbReq,loSbJson)
                IF (lnSuccess <> 1) THEN
                    ? loRest.LastErrorText
                    RELEASE loRest
                    RELEASE loJsonReq
                    RELEASE loSbReq
                    RELEASE loSbJson
                    CANCEL
                ENDIF

                IF (loRest.ResponseStatusCode <> 200) THEN
                    ? "Received error response code: " + STR(loRest.ResponseStatusCode)
                    ? "Response body:"
                    ? loSbJson.GetAsString()
                    RELEASE loRest
                    RELEASE loJsonReq
                    RELEASE loSbReq
                    RELEASE loSbJson
                    CANCEL
                ENDIF
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no property named `inventory_quantity` see http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties

I imagine what you're after is `stock_quantity`